# C++ Opengl BMP how it manages to extract width and height from header?

Tags: c++, opengl

This is my first post,so I am sorry if I write something wrong.I cannot understand how height and width are being extracted from the header.Here's the code till the part I am interested.

```
GLuint load_bmp(const char* imagepath)
{
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int imageSize;
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned char *data;

    FILE *file=fopen(imagepath,"rb");

    if(!file)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(fread(header,1,54,file)!=54)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if((header[0]!='B')||(header[1]!='M'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        dataPos=*(int*)&header[0x0A];//This line
        imageSize=*(int*)&header[0x22];//This line
        height=*(int*)&header[0x12];//This line
        width=*(int*)&header[0x16];//This line
    }
}
```

How do you get the right values using these 4 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is read into a buffer. The lines in question then cast addresses into that buffer as if they were pointing to binary integers, and read them.

So for example the height is a four-byte integer that is represented by the bytes from header[0x12] to header[0x15]. The code casts the address of the first byte as if it's pointing to an integer, then reads the contents of that integer pointer. I don't know if C++ has more guarantees about this sort of thing than C, but if not, then the code is making some assumptions about the size and byte representation of an int that won't work in some environments.